# publishing Android apps with Native C/C++ code to marketplace

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play

Are there any special requirements to upload Apps that use Native C/C++ code wrapped around with JNI, to the Android marketplace?

Thanks,

Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an APK, then you're set. All you need is the APK.

Answer (score 1):

A more complete answer is that the Android market uses the ABI (target CPU) as a filtering mechanism. If you release an APK containing native code, it will only show that APK to devices with the same CPU type. There are currently 3 supported ABI types (x86, ARMv5E, ARMv7). Google has stated that you can pack multiple ABI types into the same APK (Fat Binary), but I haven't tested this yet.